# Cambiar de base de datos en codeigniter usando hooks

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un proyecto hecho en codeigniter, que tiene una versión demo online. El proyecto es multiempresa y lo que quiero conseguir es que cada cliente tenga su propia base de datos.

La idea que tengo para esto esque en función del usuario que acceda a la web, el programa utilice una base de datos u otra.

Pare ello mi idea es crear un hook pre_controller, que lo que hace es alternar una configuracion de base de datos u otra:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Db_changer { 
     public function index() { 
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $usuario = 'pepito';

        if($usuario == 'pepito'){
            $config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
            $config['username'] = 'user_pepito';
            $config['password'] = '12345698';
            $config['database'] = 'base_de_datos_de_pepito';
            $config['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
            $config['dbprefix'] = '';
            $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
            $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $config['cachedir'] = '';
            $config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
            $config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
        }
        else
        {   
            $config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
            $config['username'] = 'user_maqnolito';
            $config['password'] = '123456789';
            $config['database'] = 'base_de_datos_de_manolito';
            $config['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
            $config['dbprefix'] = '';
            $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
            $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $config['cachedir'] = '';
            $config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
            $config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
        }

        $db = $CI->load->database($config, TRUE);
    }
}
```

Esto me da el siguiente error:

> **A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Call to a member function database() on null Filename: hooks/Db_changer.php Line
>   Number: 19 Backtrace:**

Alguien sabe qué pasa?

Comment: El $config['x'] de la linea 19 de tu código está devolviendo null, ¿cual es el campo?

Answer (score 1):

No te recomiendo para nada manejarlo con hooks. Te recomiendo manejarlo desde un inicio con una variable de sesión, la cual permita conectarse dependiendo de su valor, a una base de datos diferente desde el modelo.

Suponiendo que has hecho un script el cual ya asigna el nombre de la base de datos a utilizar y la cual llamaremos `$_SESSION["database"]`

Desde cualquier modelo, vas a inicializar los valores de conexión como si fuera lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
class Test_Model extends CI_Model {
    public $dbserver;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $config_app = array(
            'hostname' => DEFAULT_HOST_DB,
            'username' => DEFAULT_USER_DB,
            'password' => DEFAULT_PASS_DB,
            'database' => $_SESSION["database"],
            'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => TRUE
        );
        $this->dbserver = $this->load->database($config_app, TRUE);
    }
}
```

Por favor nota que nos hemos ayudado de algunas constantes, las cuales las puedes definir por defecto en el archivo `constants.php`. En este ejemplo, utilizamos varias de ellas llamadas `DEFAULT_HOST_DB (host del servidor), DEFAULT_USER_DB (nombre de usuario mysql), DEFAULT_PASS_DB (password del usuario mysql)` y por supuesto nuestra variable antes inicializada `$_SESSION["database"]` la cual contiene el nombre de la base de datos a conectar.

Después, vamos a intentar realizar consultas utilizando la variable global `$dbserver` que contendrá la conexión real de nuestra base de datos. En el mismo modelo `Test_Model` agregaremos otro método para consultar a la base de datos en cuestión, tal como:

```
public function consultarDatos($params) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cualquier_tabla";
    //nota que estamos utilizando la instancia antes creada con la conexión a nuestra base de datos dinámica en $this->dbserver
    $query = $this->dbserver->query($sql);
    if ( ! $query ) {
        return var_dump($this->dbserver->error());
    }
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

Desde tu controlador, simplemente manéjalo como de costumbre, es decir, invocando a tu modelo, ya que éste último va a hacer la magia de conectarte a la base de datos que hayas decidido antes.

**Plus**

Si antes no mencioné cómo asignarle un valor dinámico a `$_SESSION["database"]` podrías hacer uso del método `_remap` sobre escribiéndolo. Este método se llama de manera implícita de primera instancia, o sea, es el primer método de todos los existentes en tu controlador y puede ser sobre escrito para poder usarlo a conveniencia.

En nuestro caso, podríamos hacer uso de este método para determinar qué nos está llegando por medio de la url y así poner manos a la obra.

Supongamos que desde nuestro controlador principal o "por defecto", el cual definimos desde el `routes.php` como `$route['default_controller'] = 'tucontrolador';` vamos a ejecutar `_remap` para poder determinar el valor de `$_SESSION["database"]`

Con el siguiente ejemplo del funcionamiento del `_remap` el primer argumento que recibe es el nombre del método invocado. Por defecto siempre será el `index` dependiendo de nuestra configuración en `routes.php`. Sabiendo ésto, el segudno argumento que utiliza el método `_remap` son los parámetros enviados desde la url.

Quiere decir que si nosotros enviamos algo como `www.mipagina.com/empresa/microsoft` vamos a poder saber qué método y qué valores estamos recibiendo con `_remap`.

Si desde nuestro controlador (hagamos uno de prueba) llamado `Test_Controller.php` (el cual objetivamente hemos definido ya como nuestro controlador principal desde el `routes.php`) y que tenemos configurado en `routes.php` como:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'test_controller';
$route['empresa/(:any)'] = 'test_controller/index/$1';
```

Ahora escribiendo nuestro controlador, tendríamos lo siguiente:

```
<?php    
class Test_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function _remap($method, $params = array()) {
      if ( $method == "index" ) {
        $_SESSION["database"] = $params[0];
        //$params[0] equivale a microsoft si se usa la url de ejemplo www.mipagina.com/empresa/microsoft (respetando las configuraciones de nuestro routes.php)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocía la el metodo _remap. Enredaré con ello. En cuanto a la respuesta, esa solución es buena solo que en mi caso tendría que modificar  el código de los modelos. La idea es que los usuarios prueben la demo en "miservicio.com" con su propia base de datos, y si deciden contratarlo, copio su base de datos (con datos ya introducidos por ellos durante la fase demo, y copio los archivos a su propio server solo teniendo que desactivar los hooks. De ahí lo de usar hooks. No hay forma de hacerlo con hooks?

Comment: Entiendo. De hecho sí hay manera de hacerlo así, pero personalmente no lo recomiendo. Así como re configuras la conexión a la base de datos desde el modelo, puede alterar las configuraciones de los hooks, pero, volvemos a lo mismo, es dinámico, si fuera el caso de una conexión fija a diferentes bases de datos solo quedaría, de hecho, del lado del database.php pero sí veo complicado que puedas lograr algo así solo con los hooks, amigo.